# A video Converter software which uses Real hardware acceleration of AMD graphic cards

Tags: video, media-converter

in the ATI graphic driver bundle, there was an option in catalyst control center which was a video converter that used full power of card for video conversion, i've also used wondershare video converter but although they say that they use hardware acceleration for conversion, the GPU is pretty idle and only CPU is being used.
it doesn't matter whether it's paid or free, i just need a software that really uses graphic card to boost this process